# inserting the data if the column name matches with it

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data to the database. In my database i have columns like this:

```
mid, 1,2,3,4,5 till 31
```

and when a user registers (here mid is month id like 1 to 12) , i take the date on that day like this

```
$date_of_admit=date('Y-m-d');       
list($year, $month, $day) =explode("-",$date_of_admit);
$month = (int)$month;
```

now, i have to insert 'P' where the day matches, if day is 4 then it should insert 'P' in the column 4 . This i am not getting how to proceed.

please suggest

UPDATED

```
$selquery = "select * from attendance";
$columnname = mysql_field_name($selquery, $day);
```

if i can get the column name like this i can achive but i couldnt get this

Comment: 1. See normalization. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: how can i do it please explain me

Comment: You want me to explain how to read? I don't get it.

Comment: Go with this link  http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

Comment: 1,2,3,4,5 are column names ?

Comment: @ Anand Somasekhar: yes, they are my column names. I am trying to do like this... please check above for updated query